# Script to bulk git-add changes to permissionsets/profiles

Tags: profile, permissions, git, version-control

I use git for revision control of my Salesforce metadata.

I often make minor changes (adding or removing a class, field, etc) that have massive repercussions on all PermissionSet and Profile metadata files.  My colleague makes similar changes at the same time as I do.

Currently, when I make such a change, I carefully `git add -i` only the changes I wish to commit.  This is repetitive since the changes are all the same.

Has anyone written a script that only adds the changes that look like a particular regex, or anything to ease this sort of monotony? E.g.:

```
> git add-regex -- profiles/ permissions/ << EOF
<pageAccesses>
    <apexPage>MyShinyPage</apexPage>
    <enabled>.*?</enabled>
</pageAccesses>
EOF
```

Comment: I've spent a lot of time developing scripts to change permset files myself, never approached this before! I see a few interesting related StackOverflow questions that might give you a sense of how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192594/add-patch-in-git-all-hunks-matching-regex-in-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234500/git-add-lines-to-index-by-grep-regex.